# Can I mix different extensions of files on the configuration directory on node.js?

Tags: node.js, node-config

In the config directory of my application I have these files:

```
/config
 custom-environment-variables.json
 default.yaml
 production.yaml
 development.yaml
```

I need a configuration of the test of the app so I created a file `test.json` to the config directory. When I build the app I got this error:

```
Configuration property "sqlite" is not defined
```

So I change the extension of the file `test.json` to  `test.yaml` and make some change.
The build of the project runs successfully. I found [Configuration-Files](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Configuration-Files) and it mentions different extensions. So my question is why the problem occurs when I create a config file with `json` extension and pass with `yaml` extension.
Is it possible to mix the extensions of files in the config directories or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I maintain the `node-config` module. Yes, mixing extensions is supported. I have used it for years. Your problem is elsewhere.